# Unable to install ISO using rufus

Tags: software-installation, rufus

My 8 GB USB drive has been formatted and is free of all errors. Yet, I am unable to write the ISO on to the drive using Rufus. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: try Rufus 2.18. just few hours back i have done and succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should **really** check what the log from Rufus says, as it will give you an error code that you can check. Just click on the last blue button that appears left of *Start* to access the log.

Also, please be mindful that there exist a **comprehensive** FAQ for Rufus, that has a [specific entry for this error](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Error_while_partitioning_drive) telling you what you should do.

If I were to take a guess, I'd say that you probably enabled the *Controlled Folder Access* feature from Windows Defender, which of course prevents anything but whitelisted applications (such as the native ones from Microsoft) from partitioning a drive. So you will either have to disable *Controlled Folder Access* or whitelist Rufus. However, without seeing the error from Rufus' log, it's impossible to say what your issue might be. For instance the FAQ also has a list of applications that, similarly to *Controlled Folder Access*, may prevent partitioning access to a drive.

So, the answer here **really** is: check the [Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ) and follow the advice it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you try another app, to troubleshoot whether the flash drive is starting to fail or if it is a Rufus issue. https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ provides step by step instructions to:

A) Download the ISO for Ubuntu 18.04 AND make sure it downloaded AOK with [checksum verification](https://itsfoss.com/checksum-tools-guide-linux/)

B) Download the Universal Installer app for Windows from [Pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

C) Install the ISO image with FAT32 formatting as shown in the photo from the first link. If the install was successful, then the USB drive is OK and it is a Rufus issue to address by emailing pete@akeo.ie after reviewing [the Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ).